# How to download a file through a link with its extension type with scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape a website and I can download the file from the page, however everything that is being download is a plain text file. How do I download it with it's extension type? I am downloading scripts and as such, having the proper extension type on my download is necessary.

For example, if I am downloading exploits from exploit-db, the link that I go to to download them would be for example: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/19832/
and the link i would extract from there to download from is https://www.exploit-db.com/download/19832 which will, if I click on it normally, download a ruby file. But through scrapy it gets saved as a text file. Is there a way to download it as a .rb through scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

Just save it as `filename.rb`. All files are text/binary files. Extension is there just to tell your operating system what to use to understand that file. 
(In some operating systems extension isn't even required since files have headers at the beginning of the file telling what they are)

You can do try this:

`scrapy shell https://www.exploit-db.com/download/19832`

Then in the shell or your spider just do:

```
with open('ruby_file.rb', 'wb') as ruby_file:
    ruby_file.write(response.body)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what if not all the files are of the .rb extension? There are also .py and .c etc.

Comment: @dumdum you need to find a filename or reference of some sort to what it is. If you check the source code you can see it has ruby is mentioned several times for javascript code highlighting feature.

`response.xpath("//pre[contains(@class,'brush:')]").re('brush: (.+?);')` gets the programming language of the highlighter. From here you can map programming language to it's extension (there are probably couple of dozens of tools that do that on github).